# How to get width of each dom element in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

footLinks is an array of selected DOM elements via jquery. Here's the code im working on:

```
var footLinks = $('.links li');

for (var i = 0; i < footLinks.length; i++) {
    var footLink = footLinks[i];
    var footLinkWidth = footLink.width();
    console.log('Width: ' + footLinkWidth);
}
```

How do I get each element's width?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it would be better if you wrote it like this:

```
$('.links li').each(function(d) {
    console.log("Width: "+$(this).width())
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery returns object in array, and when you want to use each `DOM` element in loop that is work with JavaScript function, but `width()` is not native function, if you want to get `width` using jQuery `width()` method then create `jquery object` like `$(footLink)` so you can also use `offsetWidth` native method

```
$(footLink).width();
```

OR

```
footLink.offsetWidth;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery wrapper for the `footLink`:

```
var footLinks = $('.links li');

for (var i = 0; i < footLinks.length; i++) {
    var footLink = footLinks[i];
    var footLinkWidth = $(footLink).width();
    console.log('Width: ' + footLinkWidth);
}
```